# Mouse Controls OBJ mesh threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

When using the obj loader that three.js provides the movement around the object is very limited. How can I make it fully dynamic? E.g like on the OrbitControls three.js provides.

Here is my code so far.

```
<script>

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


        init();
        animate();


        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;




            // scene


            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
            scene.add( ambient );

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
            directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
            scene.add( directionalLight );



            // model

            var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                }
            };

            var onError = function ( xhr ) { };



            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/cylinder/' );
            mtlLoader.load( 'cylinder.mtl', function( materials ) {

                materials.preload();

                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( 'obj/cylinder/' );
                objLoader.load( 'cylinder.obj', function ( object ) {

                    object.position.y = 0;
                    scene.add( object );

                }, onProgress, onError );

            });

            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 1;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .1;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .1;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You want something like OrbitControls? Why not just use OrbitControls?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I meant. However when I try to implement it in my code the obj model is gone. How would I use it correctly? Do you know?

Comment: `However when I try to implement it in my code the obj model is gone.` Any error messages in your browser's console log? Can you show how you implement `OrbitControls`?

Comment: Just use OrbitControls. If you can't see your model I suspect... **A**: You are not implementing OrbitControls correctly. **B**: your camera is set up wrong (zoomed too far out or not looking at the model).. or **C**: Your model is not positioned where you expect (was it centered properly before export from the modelling program?).